# spring mvc passing objects with post method

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to pass submited form to my page Controller. I'm constructing JSON object like this:

```
{
"periodId": "1",
"domainId": "46",
"modelTypeId": "1",
"modelGroup": {
    "modelGroupName": "123",
    "modelGroupDescription": "abc"
}
}
```

Where I'd like to objects `*Id` to be passed as Integer and `modelGroup` as full object. So my goal is somehow make this work:

**JS file**

```
jQuery.ajax( "/Models/SaveModel", {
    type:"POST",
    dataType:'json',
    contentType:"application/json",
    data:JSON.stringify( output )
} );
```

**Page Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SaveModel", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
public
@ResponseBody
boolean createModel( SettlementModelGroup modelGroup, 
                     Integer periodId,
                     Integer domainId,
                     Integer modelTypeId )
{
    //process data here
}
```

Is it possible or do I have to make `@RequestBody String object` annotation and then parse JSON file?

Comment: spring will convert for you, i fyou get the json correct with the appropriate request parameters

Comment: Could you write an answer with example for data provided by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC by default will not do this for you - if you want to use the default approach, you can like you have said create a wrapper type with your `modelGroup`, `periodId`, `domainId`, `modelTypeId` and annotate the wrapper type with `@RequestBody`.

If you absolutely want an approach along the lines of what you have written, an approach will be to :

Create a custom annotation - say `@JsonArg`

Annotate the relevant parameters with this annotation

```
boolean createModel( @JsonArg SettlementModelGroup modelGroup, 
                     @JsonArg Integer periodId,
                     @JsonArg Integer domainId,
                     @JsonArg Integer modelTypeId );
```

Write a custom [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) which will support @JsonArg annotated arguments:

```
boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter){
  return (parameter.getParameterAnnotation(JsonArg.class)!=null);
}
```

Write logic to parse out the relevant parameter from the request body:

```
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer! I guess easier approach will be passing integers as path variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you created an object that held all 4 of the objects you list as parameters above, then you could just annotate that one parameter with `@RequestBody` and it would convert it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

After @RequestBody you must write one object, which contain model class (getters/setters)